# rehash passwords in fpass

Tags: php, mysql, hash

So I followed coding cages tutorials just to create a simple register and login website. After 3 days (I shouldn't study 2 in the night every night) I found the problem...

Anyway, now everything works except from the "forgot password" page, because when I enter a new password, it wont get hashes again..

Anyone know how to rehash the forgot password?

Link to the tutorial: http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html

And I'm really sorry for all my bad questions here..

Comment: You shouldn't use that if you're going live. If you want to know why, you can ask me. There's even someone who commented in that tutorial about it.

Comment: Hashing passwords with bare MD5 is pointless, they might as well be plain text. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) if you want to actually take this seriously. http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake on this tutorial.

To fix this just change

```
$stmt->execute(array(":upass"=>$cpass,":uid"=>$rows['userID']));
```

to

```
$stmt->execute(array(":upass"=>md5($cpass),":uid"=>$rows['userID']));
```

in Resetpass.php.

Let me know if that worked!

Comment: no that gives the website an internal error (error 500)

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like (md5($cpass))? or similar? sorry if I'm stupid xD don't wanna pay hundreds of dollars for someone on fiverr to do it in a week

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in there. Updated it now, please try again.

Comment: oh my god! it worked! Thanks alot dude! :D will let people know about this problem and your solution :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be really glad if you could mark my answer as accepted :D